# Importing an exported .FBX from Blender to Unity object transform issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform, blender, fbx

Alrighty,

I have a dumpster model I have exported from Blender as an FBX. The transform, rotation and scales have all been applied in Blender. when importing into Unity and then adding to the scene, the model is elevated and rotated at an odd angle to the transform as per the image.
The model has an armature for animating the lids an I have applied the location, rotation and scale on it as well. 
Any one else come across this or know of a fix?Thanks

[Blender image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJm8x.png)

[Incorrect dumpster transform and location image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXLa.png)

Comment: It would make sense to post two images: 1.What it looks like in Blender. 2.What it looks like in Unity

Comment: ok dont see how it will help but will do...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Blender uses the **right**-handed coordinate system which means the **Z**-axis is pointing upwards.

Unity uses the **left**-handed coordinate system which means the **Y**-axis is pointing upwards.

To fix this, set the **X**-axis rotation of the model to be -90. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and apply rotation. The **X**-axis rotation will look like it is now 0 after that. Set it to 90 again and export it to Unity.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KDwne7zQEA) 3 minutes video should also help you do this if you are still confused.

---

If you still have problems, check your animation. Don't apply it to your model and see if it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also as a side note, you can use blender files (.blend) directly with unity. So every time you modify them inside your project folder they change in unity as well.

Comment: Yea I know this also but Im using the steam version so Unity wont load the blend file......

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this would be as follows:

1. Create a dummy game object (D)
2. Transform/offset the position of D to make sure your object's position align with the dummy parent
3. Put your game object as the child of the dummy game object D

You can then apply transform on D, rather than your own game object directly.